# Maven downloading incorrect version of junit platform suite api in runtme

Tags: maven, junit5

I have a project where i added junit platform suite commons , junit platform suite engine with version 1.9.0 , when i clean install there is no issue its downloading correct version of junit platform suite api i.e 1.9.0 .

But when i add above project as dependency in other project and i do clean install or check dependency tree , its downloading incorrect version of junit platform suite api version , 1.6.3 , also in dependency tree its saying that jar is coming from the above project or jar which i created.

Can you please help here

Comment: Please show your full pom file...

Comment: Maybe using Spring Boot?  It has its own version management with different means to override it.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot attach pom , but yes second project which i mentioned is a spring boot project . Just to test my first project , i created a maven skeleton project and added the dependency , it is working fine . Some thing wrong with my spring project , still trying to figure out

Comment: ok figured it that this dependency is getting override from spring boot parent

Comment: overriding version from properties is not working , any idea of other possibilities please ?